# C# program using Selenium - Form Controls Radio Button

Tags: c#, selenium

System throws error:

> Cannot Implicitly Convert type 'Selenium Collections.Object
>   Model.ReadOnlyCollection  to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List

in this line `List<IWebElement> gender_radio = driver.FindElements(By.Name("sex"));`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/selenium_automation_practice.htm");

        List<IWebElement> gender_radio = driver.FindElements(By.Name("sex"));

         Boolean value;

        value = gender_radio.get(0).isSelected();




    }
}
```

Comment: import list from `System.Collections.Generic.List `

Comment: I have included System.Collections.Generic.List directive, but don't know how to import list from it@NarendraR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the fixes, I got the expected code:-

```
       class Program
         {
          static void Main(string[] args)
              {

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/selenium_automation_practice.htm");

       List<IWebElement> gender_radio = driver.FindElements(By.Name("sex")).ToList();

        int flag = 0;

        if(flag==0)
        {
            gender_radio[0].Click();
        }
         else
        {
            gender_radio[1].Click();

        }

    }
}
```

Find the working demo links:-
Part1:-
https://www.screencast.com/t/PZ1XQarS

Part2:-
https://www.screencast.com/t/fgPgGYbiTT

Answer (score 1):

Just make it int a list because `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>` is what return from `FindElement` method.

```
List<IWebElement> gender_radio = driver.FindElements(By.Name("sex")).ToList();
```

Comment: this fixed the error.I have another error also can you help on that  too "  ' List<IWebElement>' does not contain a definition for get and no extension method 'get' accepting a first argument of type 'List<IWebElement>'  could be found(are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)"  in the line " value = gender_radio.get(0).isSelected(); "

Comment: gender_radio[0]

Comment: the same error is coming now for .isSelected(); @Rawitas Krungkaew

Answer (score 1):

Change gender_radio to:

```
IList<IWebElement> gender_radio = driver.FindElements(By.Name("sex")); // No conversion required
```

To determine if the first element in your `IList` is selected, use:

```
bool value = false;

if (gender_radio.Any()) // using System.Linq
    value = gender_radio.First().Selected;
```

You could also do something like this, but this will throw an error if there is no `IWebElement` at index 1

```
value = gender_radio[1].Selected;
```